# Difference in multithreaded program on multprocessor and uniprocessor

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing

Is it possible for multithreaded program to differentiate between cache coherent multiprocessor machine and a uniprocessor machine with preemptive scheduling based on the value returned by loads?

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate? If this is homework, what have you tried?

Comment: @nosid: I could think of it this way, on multiprocessor machine: Suppose a processor writes some value for some address,Later that value is modified by some other processor,it will send an invalidation to the former processor. So when it will try to read the value at that address it will have a cache miss and updated value will be supplied from cache/memory. Now uniprocessor:a thread will write some value at particular address,if another thread wants to modify that value,will it have a different cache? because its a uniprocessor so I was thinking they both will write/read from same cache.